# Espresso test for Notification to showing up

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to test that when I receive push, Notification will be showing up. And it might be as well to check its properties (like title, set intent and so on.)

How can I do so?

```
 @Before
public void setupTest() {

    mData.putString(PushNotificator.KEY_PUSH_TYPE, PushType.PROJECT_OFFER.toString());
    mData.putString(PushNotificator.KEY_PUSH_OBJECT, pushObjectJsonString);
    mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();

}

@Test
public void projectOfferCreatedFromBundle() {
    mPushNotificator = new PushNotificator(mContext);
    mPushNotificator.processPush(mData);
    onView(withText("111")).check(matches(withText("111")));  //how to find notification?
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Espresso UI test framework doesn't see more than actual View. I doubt seriously that you can check any notification with Espresso.

For this purpose use another Googles testing framework `uiautomator`, which is described as:

> UI Automator is a UI testing framework suitable for cross-app functional UI testing across system and installed apps.

Here you would find how to use it with Espresso: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

More information:

- Documentation(I):
  https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/index.html
- Documentation(II):
  http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

Visit also: [Android Testing: UIAutomator vs Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076228/android-testing-uiautomator-vs-espresso/34261832#34261832)

Comment: This requires api 18 and above, I'm currently supporting 15. Can I set up instrumentation tests only for 18 and keep project minSDK 15?

Comment: it means only that you won't run your instrumentation tests on devices with lower API than the latest Jelly Bean. I think you can still keep minSDK as 15

Comment: Yes, you can keep minSDK as 15 and set test minSD as 18. Check this link: http://qathread.blogspot.ca/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html