# Android UI Test: Espresso & UIAutomator

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'd like to change the input type of the keyboard which is opened after `perform(click())`, I'm using `typeTextIntoFocusedView("Input")` to input text in a search field.

However, as mentioned I have to change the input language before inputing, so I read about UIAutomator to change the input language as told here

> [Espresso - how to switch typeText to English or other languages input mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382596/espresso-how-to-switch-typetext-to-english-or-other-languages-input-mode)

But the docs listed in the article aren't available anymore. So I wonder how I could change the input language using UIAutomator (I could use click on X,Y, but it is not really a solution).

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with the virtual keyboard? Generally, hiding the keyboard and ignoring that it even exists is a better way to build your tests. You should be able to use international characters in the string you're passing in.

Comment: Well, the emulators keyboard was on Japanese and ``typeTextIntoFocusedView("Tokyo")``  typed some Japanese symbols. So, I wonder if there is a way to change the input type or maybe another function