# Espresso - Using google espresso how to send email from Gmail app

Tags: android, android-espresso

Using google espresso I am trying to send emails using Gmail app.

In Gmail app how to access resource id for Send button: `com.google.android.id/send`

Answer (score 0):

nowadays it's impossible. Check my answer on similar issue: [Espresso test for Notification to showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467310/espresso-test-for-notification-to-showing-up)

> Espresso UI test framework doesn't see more than actual View. I doubt
>   seriously that you can check any notification with Espresso.
>
> For this purpose use another Googles testing framework `uiautomator`,
>   which is described as:
>
> > UI Automator is a UI testing framework suitable for cross-app functional UI testing across system and installed apps.
>
> Here you would find how to use it with Espresso:
>   http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html
>
> More information:
>
> - Documentation(I):    https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/index.html
> - Documentation(II):    http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html
>
> Visit also:
>   [Android Testing: UIAutomator vs Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076228/android-testing-uiautomator-vs-espresso/34261832#34261832)

As syou would see the best way to do it is using both of Espresso and uiautomator testing frameworks.