# Can I test status bar tint/color using Espresso?

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

I would like to know if there is a way to test the status bar tint displayed while using the app target. I haven't found any information about UI test related with the status bar for **Espresso**.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution  , I have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it's impossible. Espresso see only your application views, I mean it won't work with notifications, sharing intents, status bar etc.

Here's my answer on similar issue: [Espresso test for Notification to showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467310/espresso-test-for-notification-to-showing-up)

> Espresso UI test framework doesn't see more than actual View. I doubt
>   seriously that you can check any notification with Espresso.
>
> For this purpose use another Googles testing framework `uiautomator`,
>   which is described as:
>
> > UI Automator is a UI testing framework suitable for cross-app functional UI testing across system and installed apps.
>
> Here you would find how to use it with Espresso:
>   http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html
>
> More information:
>
> - Documentation(I):    https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/index.html
> - Documentation(II):    http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html
>
> Visit also:
>   [Android Testing: UIAutomator vs Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076228/android-testing-uiautomator-vs-espresso/34261832#34261832)

Check methods that `uiatomator` offers. If you won't find it, don't hesitate to add an issue on related to it code.google.com repo.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
 onView(withId(android.R.id.statusBarBackground)).check(matches(withBackgroundColor(color)));
```

You may need a color matcher:

```
public static Matcher<View> withBackgroundColor(final int colorId) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(colorId);
    int colorFromResource = ContextCompat.getColor(getTargetContext(), colorId);
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, View>(View.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            int backGroundColor = ((ColorDrawable) view.getBackground()).getColor();
            return colorFromResource == backGroundColor;
        }
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
        }
    };
}
```

Or this one:
getCurrentActivity().getWindow().getStatusBarColor();